# What happens when you don't specify RowDefinitions or ColumnDefinitions in a WPF Grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, grid

What is the logic for displaying controls within a WPF Grid when neither rows nor columns are defined for the Grid?  Likewise, if rows and/or columns are defined, what happens if you don't specify a value for the attached properties (i.e., Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0") on child controls?

Thanks!
Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the logic for displaying controls within a WPF Grid when neither rows nor columns are defined

I have seen this being used quite a bit.

```
<Grid>
   <Ellipse ... />
   <TextBlock ... />
</Grid>
```

The Ellipse will be *behind* the TextBlock, both will fill up the interior of the Grid.

It behave like a 1x1 Grid, you may set `Grid.Column="0"` but not any other value.

Answer (score 3):

You end up with one row and one column taking all available space (actually you do not have any but it *behaves* like that).

If you don't set the attached values for `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` they are 0 by default.